# I can't boot Win7 OR Ubuntu after installing Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-9.10, grub, boot

i made a partition on my new computer because i decided that i wanted to have both Win7 and Ubuntu 9.10. I made a disc image on my usb driver, and restarted my computer as to run Ubuntu without making any changes, ust to try it out. I then decided i was going to install it, so i did the whole "Install Ubuntu" ordeal, as i was running it from my usb. The installation process led me to some choices, which i did not fully understand, in the making of the partition. The thing is that Ubuntu messed with my hard drive, and now i cant access Win 7 OR Ubuntu, since i get an error as i start the computer, it says: error: file not found grub> or something along those lines. Now my computer is messed up since all i can do is start it using the ubuntu "demo" from my usb drive. Im trying to change the OS drive to "bootable" but it's taking a lot of time. I dont know if this is normal. I need help, desperately. What should i do?!

Answer (score 2):

That happens sometimes when you install from a USB thumbdrive. It doesn't happen if you install from a USB optical drive.

When the installer was doing it's thing there was an extra disk in the mix that's not there anymore.
When you remove the USB stick the disk names are all offset by 1 the next time the computer starts, so the bootloader doesn't find what it's lookiing for.

If you're lucky the bootloader was installed to one of the drives in the computer and not on the USB drive.

Windows 7 DVD can fix it, even when the automatic 'startup repair' fails. Something like fixmbr if I remember correctly. Google windows recovery console.

Or just try installing again from an Ubuntu CD so grub installs right.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you! I found another way around it, i installed ubuntu again from a live cd disk image in my usb. Using grub i then booted windows. Installed EasyBcd and there i chose to re-install the windows booting system and presto. (this is for any others who have this sort of problem, seriously, it's magic)

Thank you for your swift response.